# getStaticPaths and getStaticProps work in development but the prop is undefined in build time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am making an eCommerce platform using Next.js. In the product page, where I use dynamic routes, I used getStaticProps to fetch my product and getStaticPaths to generate the paths to the products that should be statically generated. This works perfectly in development mode but the project does not build. The product prop which is passed from getStaticProps to the page component is undefined in build time.

This is the error I get when trying to build:

> Error occurred prerendering page "/product/[id]". Read more:
> https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error TypeError: Cannot destructure
> property 'name' of 'product' as it is undefined.

```
function ProductPage({ product}) {
// product is defined in development but undefined when trying to build
const {
name,
price,
} = product;
// The rest of the component
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  connectDb();

  const products = await Product.find();
  const paths = products.map(product => ({
    params: { id: product._id.toString() },
  }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  connectDb();
  const { id } = params;
  try {
    // getting the product
    const product = await Product.findOne({ _id: id });
    return {
      props: {
        product: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product)),
      },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return {
      props: {
        product: {},
      },
    };
  }
};

export default ProductPage;
```

why is the product prop defined in development mode but undefined in build time, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Your question is declarative. Could you include a question that the community can help you with?

Comment: I would like the product prop to be defined in build time so that I do not get a build error

Comment: What’s the point of doing this: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product))`?

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered the exact same issue. I'm not sure what you have put in your `//the rest of the component` section but I noticed in the `getStaticPaths` function you specify `fallback: true`. Make sure you handle this in the page component by adding a skeleton or a loading indicator for pages that didn't yet exist at build time. That did the trick for me.

Comment: Great, this actually worked thank you! reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-false

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the code it seems like the product is undefined likely because the code in the try block failed to return data (or you didn't find a matching document in the MongoDB database?). Can you verify that no error occurs?

This can happen if you're passing the id param as "string" while in your MongoDB database the _id field is of type "ObjectID".  You can remedy that by converting the "id" string to an ObjectID using the MongoDB package.